# Tee-Object -Variable not sending to stdout

Tags: powershell, tee

I have a piece of script with the following line:

```
myBinary.exe --param1 a -param2 b | Tee-Object -Variable "myVar"
```

It used to stream the output just fine. Now that I moved this line into a function, it no longer streams to standard out and only populate the variable `myVar`.

Any idea how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have enough information to diagnose your problem, but there's a **`Tee-Object` pitfall** that *may* explain your symptoms:

As of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.0.0-rc:

**If `Tee-Object` doesn't receive any *success* output via the pipeline, it leaves the target variable's *previous* value untouched** or, if there's no preexisting variable by that name, does *not* create it.

```
# Run command that produces stdout and therefore PS success-stream output.
cmd /c 'echo hi' | Tee-Object -Variable myVar

# Stdout -> success output was correctly captured in $myVar.
$myVar  # -> 'hi'

# Run another command that *doesn't* produce any stdout output
# (only stderr output).
cmd /c 'echo NO >&2' | Tee-Object -Variable myVar

# !! Perhaps unexpectedly, the previous value of $myVar was NOT cleared.
$myVar # -> !! STILL 'hi'
```

This unintuitive behavior has been [reported on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5560).

The - cumbersome - workaround is to explicitly set the target variable to `$null` first:
`$myVar = $null`

---

Thus, perhaps what you're seeing in `$myVar` is a *preexisting* value that the - now seemingly non-stdout-output-producing - `myBinary.exe ... | Tee-Object ...` call didn't clear.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have isolated the issue and it seems like the problem only occurs if the `Tee-Object` is in a function

Comment: @user1763590: The issue may still be the same; note that a function sees variables defined in _ancestral_ scopes, so if there's a `$myVar` in the _global_ scope, for instance, the function would see it too, and with a command that doesn't produce stdout / success output, the `Tee-Object` call will _not_ create a local copy that shadows the ancestral one.

Comment: I know this is old but the issue is still present; is there a workaround? Redirect stderr to stdout? In my case I'm invoking a git push command which _I think_ is only resulting in stderr output (not intuitive at all) so I'm seeing this same issue.

Comment: @kamranicus, the - cumbersome - workaround is to explicitly set the target variable to `$null` first.